# JSON and ASP.NET WebMethod not firing server side method

Tags: javascript, c#, json, webmethod

I'm trying to pass parameters to my code behind with **WebMethod**.

I'm reaching the success end of ajax but the method in my aspx.cs code behind doesn't get called and I have error.

> Operation failed! Details :'[object Object]

I'm using a masterpage if it makes a difference.

How to do resolve this ?

Please, can you help me ?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=imgfasi]").bind("click", function () {
            var fasi = {};
            fasi.Txseltlc = $("[id*=txseltlc]").val();
            fasi.Txrescldisa = $("[id*=txrescldisa]").val();
            fasi.Ddlauttlc = $("[id*=ddlauttlc]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Savepnfasi",
                data: '{fasi: ' + JSON.stringify(fasi) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == "1") {
                        alert("Success!");
                    } else {
                        alert("Operation failed! Details: " + response);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

code behind :

```
public class pnfasiweb
{
    public string Txseltlc { get; set; }
    public string Txrescldisa { get; set; }
    public string Ddlauttlc { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static void Savepnfasi(pnfasiweb fasi)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"]))
    {         
        string ProductID = Mpskmt3.Base64ForUrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());

        string sql = String.Format(@" UPDATE `dotable` ");
        sql += String.Format(" SET ");
        sql += String.Format(" Aut = ?, ");
        sql += String.Format(" Res = ?, ");
        sql += String.Format(" Dur = ?, ");
        sql += String.Format(" Comp = CASE WHEN Comp IS NULL THEN ? ELSE CONCAT(Comp, '; ', ?) END, ");
        sql += String.Format(" doDateHour = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ");
        sql += String.Format(" WHERE ID = ?; ");

        using (OdbcConnection cn =
                new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQLlocalhost"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (OdbcCommand command =
                    new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();                       
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", fasi.Ddlauttlc.ToString());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", Convert.ToInt32(fasi.Txrescldisa.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", Convert.ToInt32(fasi.Txseltlc.ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param4", Mpskmt3.Container.TheObjectPropertyName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param5", Mpskmt3.Container.TheObjectPropertyName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param6", ProductID.ToString());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
       //Error
    }
}
```

**#Edit01**

[image]

Comment: A few pointers when debugging: don't throw ex;, just `throw;`. This way you can stack trace. Don't alert your errors, console.log them. Set breakpoints in javascript and debug in chrome console. Also for alerting objects, don't concatenate strings to them. Finally, if you want to see your message clearly on the client side, try using `response.data`

Comment: @JeffLi Thank you, I have added `response.data` and in the output I have correctly values. Please see my **#Edit01** in my first question

Comment: write an `error:function(e){ alert(e); }` for the ajax and you can find what error it is

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth Thanks but when write your suggestion ?

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth The problem is `string ProductID = Mpskmt3.Base64ForUrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());` because JSON using POST method and I try update query with `QueryString` method... please can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var qString = "?" + window.location.href.split("?")[1];
var fasi = {};

...

url: "Default.aspx/Savepnfasi" + qString,
data: '{fasi: ' + JSON.stringify(fasi) + '}',
```